# Case when condition in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute a condition in SQL Server but it doesn't work.

This is my code

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please provide actual code, not a screenshot

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Anyone who wants to help you has to retype everything. Many users will just move along.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `case` expression with query :

```
select distinct declaration,
       (case when type_id_emet_vent = 'cib' then d_emetteur_vendeur 
             when type_id_emet_vent = 'lei' then a.code_cib
        end) as cid_emetteure
from p1 left join
     a
     on p1.id_emetteur_vendeur in (code_lei, code_afc);
```